# javascript:history.back(-1) issue caused by <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, back

Hi I am using a <kbd>Button</kbd> to go back to the ***previous page*** in our app [*the code I use ↓* ]

```
<a class="back-page" href="javascript:history.back(-1)"></a>
```

This is working perfectly too. My real issue with some `ID`'s in my view page. If a user **click** on  some of the anchot tag with `ID`'s linked, then he has to click that much time <kbd>Back Button</kbd> to redirect to the previous page.

**What I need is that no matter how much `ID`'s he have click, *if he click to the* <kbd>Back Button</kbd> then the page should redirect to the previous page**.

I have tried some method's ↓

**First**

```js
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
```

**Second**

```html
<a href="javascript: history.go(1)">Go Back</a>
```

**Third**

```js
$(".back-page").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    history.back(1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="back-page" href="javascript:void(0);">Back</a>
```

*The code of the anchot tag with ID  ↓*

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#t1">Personal Info</a></li>
  <li><a href="#t2">Address(s)</a></li>
  <li><a href="#t3">Social Info</a></li>
  <li><a href="#t4">More Info</a></li>
</ul>
```

*None of this helped me*, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us the ID button?

Comment: @Jonasw I will put the code.

Comment: do you have self anchor tags only as part of `ID` i don't see any button here

Comment: @Niladri sorry bro my mistake. I ment anchor tags not buttons. Sorry once again

Comment: @weBer it should be either `window.history.back(); or history.go(-1)` in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that clicking one of the IDs adds another history entry. To prevent this we could do:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a")
  .forEach(function(link){
     if(link.href.includes( location.href + "#")){
       //we stay on the page, prevent redirects:
       link.addEventListener("click", function(event){
         event.preventDefault(); //the redirect
         //scroll:
         document.getElementById( link.href.split("#")[1] )
         .scrollIntoView();
      });
    }
  });
```

---

If you want to change the url ( and the history), we need to count the history entries we make, and then the back button needs to go back that amount:

```
var count = 1;

document.querySelectorAll("a")
  .forEach(link =>
     link.onclick = () =>  count++
  );
```

So then to go back:

```
history.go( - count );
```